How to Mock a Boolean Hook and a Database Update Call Within a Custom Hook to Bypass Them
The issue I am facing is that I have a custom hook that is asynchronous and does three main things:
A. It makes a check; if the check is true, it continues.
B. It makes a Firebase call; if successful, it continues to modify the Redux store.
C. It adds the data to the Redux store.
The issue right now is that within the tests, I can only test this asynchronous function if I comment out steps A and B, due to the fact that I cannot mock A and B properly. Do you have any idea how to mock an internal hook as well as a Firestore action to be successful, thus allowing the code to get to the Redux part?


 
 // Custom Hook 
 const pasteCopiedDay = async () => {
    try {
        // 1st Mock needed
        if (!showBackdrop('Saving')) return;
        // 2nd Mock needed as success
        await updateDoc(programNestedDocRef, payload)
        // 3rd The Actual test
        dispatch(pasteDay(handleWeekMutations(modifications)));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      errorHandling(error, 'Global globalPaste,ts');
    }
  };





// React
import { ReactNode } from 'react';
// Redux
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import authReducer from '../../redux-store/authSlice';
// Custom Hooks
import useCopySystem from './useCopySystem';

const createTestStore = () =>
  configureStore({
    reducer: {
      auth: authReducer,
      global: globalReducer,
      misc: miscReducer,
    },
  });

const testStore = createTestStore();

const wrapper = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => <Provider store={testStore}>{children}</Provider>;

describe('test copySystem', () => {
 
  const {
    result: {
      current: { pasteCopiedDay /*, pasteCopiedMainGroup */ },
    },
  } = renderHook(() => useCopySystem(), { wrapper });

  it('pasteCopiedDay', async () => {
  
    // Mock first hook as successfull
    beforeEach(() => {
      jest.mock('../utilities/useBackdrop', () => ({
        useBackdrop: () => ({
          showBackdrop: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true),
          closeBackdrop: jest.fn(),
        }),
      }));
    });
    
    
   // Mock Await firestore function as successfull
   // ????
   
   
   // Call the asnych test hook fn
   await pasteCopiedDay('day3Id', mockedCopyDayType);

   // Check the state if the data has been copied
   const result = testStore.getState().global.copy
   
    expect(result).toEqual(mockedExpectedMainGroups);
  });




Why did you call the pasteCopiedDay directly？Is it a function that should be triggered by user event? Show the component and how did you use the useBackdrop hook
